# Alternative ways to Remove Constant Columns and Certain Column names in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the following code to remove constant columns and columns with certain headings.

Is there a more pythonic way to do it ?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=1000,
                           n_features=6,
                           n_informative=3,
                           n_classes=2,
                           random_state=0,
                           shuffle=False)

# Creating a dataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'car':X[:,0],
                                  'ball':X[:,1],
                                  'Feature 3': 5,
                                  'Feature 4':X[:,3],
                                  'Feature 5':X[:,4],
                                  'Feature 6':X[:,5],
                                  'Class':y})
one = df.std().eq(0).reindex(df.columns, fill_value=True)
two = one.index.str.contains("ball|car")
all = one| two


df_auto = df.loc[:, ~all].copy()
```

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: @jezrael kindly check the update

Comment: @jezrael i added a constant value column

Comment: In my opinion your solution is perfectly.

Comment: @jezrael alright, i think i should delete my question then,  I thought there might be a single line than can execute this without creating copies and copying columns

Comment: There is anwer, so is not possible delete it. Be free accept answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no obvious issues with your current logic. "Pythonic" is subjective and I offer a different solution below.

This is an alternative `numpy` + `.iloc` based method which you may prefer:

```
n1 = np.where(np.std(df.values, axis=0) == 0)[0]
n2 = np.where(df.columns.str.contains('ball|car'))[0]

df_auto = df.iloc[:, np.delete(range(len(df.columns)), np.hstack((n1, n2)))].copy()
```